# Error refreshing state: state snapshot was created by Terraform v0.15.0, which is newer than current v0.12.18

Tags: terraform, version

Issue happens when trying run terraform plan command.

```
Error refreshing state: state snapshot was created by Terraform v0.15.0,
which is newer than current v0.12.18; upgrade to Terraform v0.15.0
or greater to work with this state
```

[image: Error refreshing state: state snapshot was created by Terraform v0.15.0, which is newer than current v0.12.18; upgrade to Terraform v0.15.0 or greater to work with this state]

Comment: Please don't include images of either code or errors as they are harder for users to read. You can instead use code block formatting and copy the error message or relevant code into that.

Answer (score 2):

The same reply to this ticket https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69575643/ Which I expect to be related.

Happened to me, my deployment (CICD) failed and left a lock in the TF state.

So I just went and manually removed the lock from my local

`terraform init -backend-config="key=prod/app1.tfstate"`

`terraform force-unlock -force xxxxx-8df6-a7e8-46a8-xxxxxxxxxxxx`

Then I try to redeploy from CI/CD and get that error, because my local was higher version than terraform running in the CI/CD.

In the end, I did this to restore to the previous state:

1. S3: find the state file, restore the old version (versioning enabled in this bucket)
2. Run this again: `terraform init -backend-config="key=prod/app1.tfstate" -reconfigure`

To get the response below with the previous digest value:

```
Successfully configured the backend "s3"! Terraform will automatically
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.
Error refreshing state: state data in S3 does not have the expected content.

This may be caused by unusually long delays in S3 processing a previous state
update.  Please wait for a minute or two and try again. If this problem
persists, and neither S3 nor DynamoDB are experiencing an outage, you may need
to manually verify the remote state and update the Digest value stored in the
DynamoDB table to the following value: ebf597a8a25619b959baaa34a7b9d905
```

3. Update the dynamo item with the digest above
4. Run deployment again

Answer (score 0):

Actually this happens, when there is a difference in terraform version. Consider below example
Initial state snapshot is created for terraform version "v0.15.0" and current terraform state update is done with version "v0.12.18"(which is older than the state snapshot)

In order to make it work we need allow terraform state to work with specific list of terraform version.

> terraform {   required_version >= "=0.12.18" }

This will make terraform state files to work with versions above than "0.12.18"